# Java Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK gives wrong day

Tags: java, date, dayofweek, java.util.calendar

What is wrong with the below code? It gives wrong day for any date of the year.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Calendar;
public class Solution {
    public static String getDay(String d, String m, String y) {

        String[] days = {"SUNDAY", "MONDAY", "TUESDAY", "WEDNESDAY", "THURSDAY", "FRIDAY", "SATURDAY"};
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Integer.parseInt(y), Integer.parseInt(m), Integer.parseInt(d)); 
        return days[c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1]; 
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String m = in.next();
        String d = in.next();
        String y = in.next();

        System.out.println(getDay(d, m, y));
    }
}
```

Comment: Provided 3, 5, 2018, and got THURSDAY back, which is right. Can you provide example of failed scenarios?

Comment: I tried 08 05 2015 (august 5, 2015) and the result was SATURDAY instead of Wednesday.

Comment: @clement The order in the code is month day-of-month year. March 5 2018 was a Monday, so when you got THURSDAY it was incorrect.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: @OleV.V. damn american date format, we use dd/mm/yyyy here in Australia (same in France ;) ), 3rd of May 2018 is indeed a Thursday :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See the documentation for the `Calendar` class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set-int-int-int-

The value for month is 0-indexed, so if you provide `3` as the month value, it is interpreted as "April".

Comment: Thank you very much. I correct the MONTH by deducting one from input value, and it worked.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! It's a bit strange that month is zero indexed because calendars obviously don't start at 0 and end at 11. I spent a lot of time trying to debug my code :/

Answer (score 3):

It’s easiest to have the `Scanner` read `int` values rather than strings:

```
    int m = in.nextInt();
    int d = in.nextInt();
    int y = in.nextInt();

    System.out.println(LocalDate.of(y, m, d).getDayOfWeek());
```

When I feed `5 4 2018` (today’s date), I get `FRIDAY`, which is correct.

If you must use strings:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/u");

    String m = in.next();
    String d = in.next();
    String y = in.next();

    System.out.println(LocalDate.parse(m + '/' + d + '/' + y, dateFormatter).getDayOfWeek());
```

The `Calendar` class you were using is long outdated, poorly designed and sometimes cumbersome to work with. Instead I recommend `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer. For one little thing it numbers the months of the year in the same way humans do.

Also the names of the days of the week are built-in, so don’t reinvent the wheel. Your strings coincide with the names of the values of the `DayOfWeek` enum in `java.time`, so just print those to get the strings you want. If you don’t want all uppercase or you want the day names in another language, use `DayOfWeek.getDisplayName` or a `DateTimeFormatter`.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.